# Are variables declared in module scope not properties of the module object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In browsers global variables are actually properties of `window` object.

If I declare a variable with `var` keyword in Node.js then will it be a property of `module` object?

```
var aaa = 'aaa';
console.log(module.aaa); // undefined
```

Why is it undefined? Doesn't module object in Node.js follow the same logic as global object in browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will it be a property of module object?

No, and that explains why it is `undefined`. Anything defined inside a module is enclosed in that module unless exposed explicitly via `exports` or `module.exports`.

Comment: So it will be like a "normal" local variable? Like local variables in functions that aren't properties of any object? Just to make sure I understand correctly